# HTML Rendering - Adding extra code (Internet Explorer)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, html-rendering, radeditor

I am using **Telerik Rad Editor** in my project, i have an issue with the way HTML is rendered in editor.
I have discovered some changes that are not ideal. Try this as an example. switch to HMTL Mode and enter the following code.

```
<!--* 
<a href="http://www.chillisauce.co.uk/hen-nights/"><img alt="Chillisauce Hen Nights" src="http://www.chillisauce.co.uk/includes/email/email_header_hen.jpg" /></a> *-->
```

These "" tags are added by us so that when html is viewed in design mode that part of code is not visible but is actually part of my template.

Now switch to Design Mode and then back to HTML Mode. You will notice that additional code has been added...

```
<!--* <a href="http://www.chillisauce.co.uk/hen-nights/" originalAttribute="href" originalPath="http://www.chillisauce.co.uk/hen-nights/"><img alt="Chillisauce Hen Nights" src="http://www.chillisauce.co.uk/includes/email/email_header_hen.jpg" originalAttribute="src" originalPath="http://www.chillisauce.co.uk/includes/email/email_header_hen.jpg" /></a> *-->
```

If you switch to Design Mode and then back to HTML Mode again, these additional bits will have been added again.

Is there any way to disable that functionality?

**EDIT:**

I have installed new version of Telerik Controls but I found that this is problem in IE. In other browsers like Fire Fox this works OK but In IE it adds that extra line of code.I have checked and this issue occurred in IE version (6,8 and 9).
Actually i am loading Rad Editor control in "Web Browser Control" in my windows application.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar bug report in Telerik Rad Editor forum. 
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/originalpath-originalattribute-injected-into-content.aspx

The admin said that it was a bug and should fixed in version 5.7.2. you can try upgrade your Telerick Rad Editor to the lastest version.

Comment: Thanks @opps, let me try new version.

Comment: this problem is only in IE other browsers are doing fine. We are using browser control in our windows app so IE problem is in our app. We have wrote this to Telerik but they don't have any solution of this yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code on the online demos on Telerik's site - http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

The problem does not happen there, so it's most probably a bug that has already been fixed. You should get a newer version of the Telerik controls and upgrade your project.

Comment: this problem is only in IE other browsers are doing fine. We are using browser control in our windows app so IE problem is in our app. We have wrote this to Telerik but they don't have any solution of this yet.